# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Hi I have a dataframe PL_join_LFD_ranked as below:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+
|FACILITY_ID|LOCATION_ID|PATIENT_ID|DISTANCE|CAPACITY|rank_distance|
+-----------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+-------------+
|FAC003     |LOC0001    |P1        |54      |3       |2            |
|FAC002     |LOC0001    |P1        |45      |2       |1            |
|FAC003     |LOC0001    |P2        |54      |3       |2            |
|FAC002     |LOC0001    |P2        |45      |2       |1            |
|FAC006     |LOC0010    |P3        |12      |2       |1            |
|FAC003     |LOC0010    |P3        |54      |3       |4            |
```

fac_cap_map is as below

```
Map(FAC004 -> 0, FAC003 -> 0, FAC007 -> 0, FAC002 -> 0, FAC006 -> 0, FAC005 -> 0)
```

I want to create a new column current capacity ,for its calculation I created a UDF .

```
def cur_cap_udf(m: Map[Any, Int]) = udf( (cap: Int,fac:String) =>
      m foreach {case (key,value) => if ((key == fac) && (value < cap) ) value +1 else value}

    )
```

calling the udf

```
val finaldf1 = PL_join_LFD_ranked.withColumn("current_capacity", cur_cap_udf(fac_cap_map)(PL_join_LFD_ranked("CAPACITY"),PL_join_LFD_ranked("FACILITY_ID")))
```

Error I am getting is as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Unit is not supported
```

Reason
Foreach returns unit type. Tried using Foldleft ,but foldleft is used when there is result from last operation is needed. But this is not the case here.

I am just checking if value in map is less than capacity passed to udf and then increment map value by 1. This is logic for current capacity.

Comment: Your UDF doesn't returns anything use map instead of foreach

Answer (score 0):

I think, your question is not related to Spark, but to "how to return Integer `value` from `cur_cap` function".
Also, digging a bit into the function, what result do you want to get, what kind of dataframe?

As far as I understand, with current code every facility will be evaluated separately, so `(key == fac)` would be `True` only once for each row.
Maybe you should try looking into `PL_join_LFD_ranked.groupBy(col("FACILITY_ID").agg(sum("CAPACITY")))`, and then process capacity somehow after that? (maybe, `.withColumn("capped_capacity", f.min("capacity_sum", "capacity_cap")`)

Answer (score 0):

```
def cur_cap_udf(m: Map[Any, Int]) = udf( (cap: Int,fac:String) =>
      val value = map.getOrElse(fac, cap)
      if(value<cap){
        value+1
      }else{
        value
      }

)
```

You need to return value from udf. `foreach` returns unit, hence the error.